# C# WPF Сериализация динмаического объекта Button, внутри объекта StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf

В проекте возникла проблема с сериализацией динамических Buttonо'в, которые пользователь создает по ходу программы, внутри buttonо'в, соответствеено, содержится информация, которая необходим для работы программы. Вот один из примеров заполнения кнопки

```
XmlReader readxml = XmlReader.Create(textBox.Text);
var feed = SyndicationFeed.Load<SyndicationFeedEx>(readxml);
feed.SourceUri = textBox.Text;

int Z = Stackpnelleft.Children.Count +1;
if (Z == 0) { Z++; };

TextBlock TX = new TextBlock();
Button ButtonTitle = new Button();
ContextMenu contextmenu = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem mi = new MenuItem();

TX.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
TX.Text = feed.Title.Text;
TX.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
ButtonTitle.Content = TX;

//ButtonTitle.Uid = "BBB" + Z + "";
ButtonTitle.Tag = feed;

ButtonTitle.ToolTip = ""+ feed.SourceUri + "";

ButtonTitle.ContextMenu = contextmenu;
mi.Header = "Удалить";
mi.Tag = ButtonTitle;
mi.Click += Delete_Channel;

l = TX.Text;
ButtonTitle.Click += OnFeedClick;

contextmenu.Items.Add(mi);
Stackpnelleft.Children.Add(ButtonTitle);
```

Соответсвенно, таких кнопок множество. Вопрос давольно прост: как научить программу запоминать эти кнопки при окончании сеанса, а при начале нового сеанса воспроизводить те, что были при закрытии.

Comment: Никакой проблемы нет. UI-элементы не предназначены для сериализации. Воспользуйтесь MVVM, создайте модельный объект «кнопка», его и сериализируйте.

Comment: Хотя-бы какой-то пример, бегло прогуглил ничего того что надо не нашел.

Comment: Ну, пример сваять сложно, работы много. Сериализация — непростая тема. Вы хотя бы с MVVM знакомы? Идея в том, что (1) вы заводите обычный класс или несколько классов, которые описывают ваши контролы, (2) вы сохраняете нужные данные из контролов в набор таких вот объектов, которые вы описали в пункте 1, (3) к набору объектов применяете обычную сериализацию.

Answer (score 2):

Есть 2 возможных варианта. Лёгких и простых среди них нет.

Вариант первый: Сериализация. Всё так, как уже писал VladD. Создаётся класс, с помощью которого объект сериализуется и десереализуется. Работает это по следующему принципу: В конструктор класса передаётся визуальный объект который берётся за основу. Далее в конструкторе класс вытягивает из объекта все те его свойства которые вам необходимо сохранить и, в последствии, по ним восстановить объект (ширина, высота, положение, контент и т.д). После создания объекта вы скармливаете его одному из стандартных сериализаторов (можно и свой сделать). Примерно так:

```
public void SaveTemplate(string filename)
    {
        VisualElementList.Clear();
        AddNewVisualElement(CurentField);

        foreach (UIElement curent in CurentField.Children)
        {
            AddNewVisualElement((FrameworkElement)curent);
        }

        Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create);
        SoapFormatter formatter = new SoapFormatter();

        //BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        //XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(VisualElement));


    formatter.Serialize(stream, VisualElementList.ToArray());
        stream.Close();
    }
```

В вашем распоряжении 3 стандартных сериализатора: BinaryFormatter, SoapFormatter  и XmlSerializer. На MSDN'e есть их подробное описание.

Обратный процесс (восстановление объектов) выглядит примерно так: Вы открываете файл и скармливаете его тому сериализатору которым вы туда записывали данные. Примерно так:

```
    public void LoadTemplate(Stream FileStream)
        {
            try
            {
                using (FileStream)
                {
                    SoapFormatter formatter = new SoapFormatter();
                    VisualElementList.Clear();
VisualElementList.AddRange((VisualElement[])formatter.Deserialize(FileStream));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                /*Сериализаторы очень капризны и придирчивы к формату. Добавите в сериалиуемый объект новое поле и всё, старые файлы перестанут сериализоваться.*/
            }
        }
```

Далее немаловажный нюанс: Ваши объекты на основании их состояния (значений всех их свойств) должны уметь создавать визуальные объекты. Т.е. если вы сделали класс MySButton то он должен иметь метод типа GetButton который возвращает объект класса Button идентичный тому, который передали в конструктор MySButton. 
Вы в цикле обходите всю коллекцию десериализованных объектов, из каждого вытягиваете его базовый визуальный объект и добавляете его на свою форму. Всё.

Вариант второй: XamlReader и XamlWriter.
Как понятно из имён данных классов они работают с Xaml разметкой (соответственно вариан работает только для WPF и пр. использующих данную разметку фв) Подробнее о классах читайте на MSDN'е

XamlWriter умеет генерить разметку по переданному ему визуальному объекту
XamlReader соответственно умеет создавать объекты по переданной ему разметке.

Примерно так:

```
  FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
            XamlWriter.Save(VEObj, fs);//VEObj -объект класса UIElement

 Stream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
        VEObj = XamlReader.Load(fs) as UIElement;
```

Второй вариант кажется проще, но в работе классов XamlReader и XamlWriter есть множество нюансов. Не каждый контрол и не все их свойства они смогу корректно сохранить и восстановить.

PS: Вся работа с визуальными объектами должна идти в STA потоке (графическом потоке) соответственно ваш UI на время десереализации и восстановления состояния будет фризится.

Comment: Ну, если связывать свойства с UI не через вычитывание в конструкторе, а через Binding, и выгружаете сериализацию в фоновый поток, фризов не будет. Но это, конечно, повышает сложность решения.